# Date not changing using left right arrow in Jquery Datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, events, model-view-controller, datepicker

**I have multiple datepicker control in a page.** I have customized all the  datepicker controls to display only `month` and `year`. When we try to change the date using the month/year dropdown, it works. **When I am trying to change date using the left/right arrow, it does not work all the time.**

Try changing the date in the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DarshikaJBhatt/wvhb3pyz/13/) page and click the `DONE` button after changing the date using the left/right arrow. Sometime it works and sometime it doesn't.

Comment: are you sure identity of elements that you binded date picker to are different